# three.js mouse event handler

Tags: three.js, webgl

I    am    new    using    three.js.    I    have    created    a    mesh    cube    and    want    to    make    it    disappear    by    mouse    click.    how    can    i    do    that?    any    help    or    good    tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things you can do depending on what you want.

1. You can remove it from the scene (scene.remove()).
2. You can make it transparent (material.transparent = true; material.opacity = 0.0;)
3. You can move it out of the view.